# Upgrading OpenJPA version from 2.2.0 to 2.4.3

Tags: openjpa

I am getting issue with upgrading OpenJPA 2.2.0 to 2.4.3. I've added 2.4.3 jar in my project library. I'm missing some peoperties regarding compatibility in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using Tomcat or TomEE?  there may be some differences in code formatting between 2.2.0 and 2.4.3.   can you give a specific example?

Comment: i'm using websphere server. But problem comes when i try to run a batch/scheduled job.

Comment: is your problem starting a transaction with @transactional annotation?

Comment: No, I haven't used annotations. Its with starting of the whole scheduler job. It says Java Class not found even with all the class paths being set properly.